# Intermediate $\mathsf{NP}$-complete problems?

Tags: computational-complexity, np

Partition problem is weakly NP-complete since it has polynomial (pseudo-polynomial) time algorithm if input integers are bounded by some polynomial. However, 3-Partition problem is strongly NP-complete problem (even if input integers are bounded by a polynomial).

> **Assuming, $\mathsf{P \ne NP}$, Can we prove that intermediate NP-complete problems must exist? If the answer is yes, Is there such "natural" candidate problem?**

Here, **Intermediate NP-complete** problem is an NP-complete problem that neither has a pseudo-polynomial time algorithm nor NP-complete in the strong sense.

I guess that there is an infinite hierarchy of intermediate NP-complete problems between weak NP-completeness and strong NP-completeness.

An alternative way to pose the question is:

> **Assuming, $\mathsf{P \ne NP}$, Can we prove the existence of NP-complete problems that neither have polynomial time algorithm nor NP-complete when the numerical
>   inputs are presented in unary? If the answer is yes, Is there such "natural" candidate problem?**

The reverse direction of the implication is true. The existence of such "intermediate" $NP$-complete problems implies $\mathsf{P \ne NP}$ because if $\mathsf{ P=NP}$ then unary $NP$-complete problems are in $P$.

This was posted on [CSTheory StackExchange](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/16692/intermediate-mathsfnp-complete-problems).